# Red Faction Guerrilla - rebuild/reset all buildings?

Tags: pc, red-faction-guerrilla

In Red Faction Guerrilla, I see that the more buildings I destroy, the more size the save file increases, that means (I think) the save file actually stores which buildings get destroyed. I have completed the game but I don't see the buildings rebuild. So does anyone know how to rebuild the building? (I'm thinking about using a save file editor to remove the destroyed buildings that get stored).

What I want is full map, full weapon, full buildings (and bridges).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I want is full map, full weapon, full buildings (and bridges).

Easy.
Step 1: Download [Mod Manager by HazardX](https://www.factionfiles.com/ff.php?action=file&id=517005)

Step 2: Read the readme file of Mod Manager, then just copy the content of Mod Manager into the game's folder
[image: Install Mod Manager]

Step 3: Run ModManager.exe (which you just copied in step 2), then select the mods (Freeroam Mode: give you full map & Free Upgrades: give you full weapon), then click "Activate Mods".
[image: Activate mod]

Step 4: Run game & start new game (give you full buildings and bridges), then save game.

From now on, just run the game & you get: **full map, full weapon, full buildings (and bridges)**.

Enjoy!